# Chille Plant buds are falling

Tags: chili

[image][image: chillie plant]I am from Mumbai. This photos I took in winter. My chille plants buds are falling after flowering. I daily watered less to plants. I put fertilizer every two months.I want to know how polinated chillie buds are falling after few days?I use vermicompost. How to water less?

---

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it with new information. Thanks and welcome to the site.

Comment: The plant looks strange. No leaves on bottom part. This is the first problem. Try to water less the plant. Chili likes dry soils (especially if you want more stronger one). Which fertilizer do you use?

Comment: I use vermicompost. How to water less?

Comment: Have you tried giving it extra phosphorus?

Answer (score 1):

Your Chille is getting too tall. I would suggest you prune it back to a more manageable height. You might also want to consider adding some more support sticks. Note how all the growth exists on only one side of the stem, the side facing the light. I would suggest you rotate the plant once or twice a week to help ensure a more even distribution of light which, in turn, should help the plant to grow in a more stable fashion.